# Get custom return value from procedure

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

I have this type in `ORACLE`:

```
create or replace  type error_record is object(
    error         number(1),
    error_message varchar2(500));
```

The stored proc returns this type:

```
function some_func(params....) return error_record;
```

I am struggling with the code to execute this function and get a return value. Every example I see uses `OracleDbType.Object` but there is no such enum value.

```
using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(...))
{
    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("some_func", con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        var pResult = new OracleParameter();
        //pResult.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Object;
        pResult.UdtTypeName = "error_record";
        pResult.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(pResult);

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: The enum value `OracleDbType.Object` exists for me - which version of ODP.NET are you using?  I'm using Oracle.DataAccess version 4.112.2.0.

Comment: Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/12.1.24160419/

Comment: ODP.NET Managed Driver does not support user-defined types: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/featUDTs.htm

Comment: @LukeWoodward, hmm I was reading the same page but somehow missed that note :(  Thank you so much!!

Comment: Sounds like in your case all you need is to return a `varchar2`. If the return is NULL - no error. Otherwise - error